# How to grep a certain value, in a returned table format result, including an adb command

Tags: android, shell, grep, adb

```
D:\WORK\git\target>adb shell vmstat
procs -----------memory---------- ---swap-- -----io---- -system-- ----cpu----
 r  b   swpd   free   buff  cache   si   so    bi    bo   in   cs us sy id wa
 3  1 131096  78612 130452 1037964   1    2   304   146    1  292  7  7 86  0
```

So i have this result when i run the above command. I need to use an adb command that returns me the free memory. Something like this:

```
adb shell vmstat | grep 'free'
```

Of course this does not work. Any ideas ? Thanks

Comment: So you have picked the wrong tool for the job. Then realized and acknowledged your mistake. Yet proceeded with using it as a tag and putting it in your title. How's that helpful?

Answer (score 0):

I found a hardcoded command so far:

```
adb shell "vmstat | awk 'NR ==3' | awk '{print $4}'"
```

Comment: no need to pipe multiple instances of `awk` - you can do `vmstat | awk 'NR==3{print $4}'`